# Is there any way to make the screenshot output 'tile' that appears in the bottom right corner, appear on all displays?

Tags: screen-capture

I'm running macOS 13.5 on a 13 inch MacBook Pro M1 2020 with a second monitor. I use Shift-Cmd-4 to take screenshots often, but the output preview only appears on the primary monitor. Is there a tweak that can make it appear on both monitors?
I know the default behaviour of the app switcher can be altered to appear on both screens with `defaults write com.apple.dock appswitcher-all-displays -bool true; killall Dock`... I'm looking for something similar.
Thanks!